# Heroku Pre-compilation Breaks My JavaScript. Without Pre Compiling It gives a 500 server error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have just included one javascript in my application which will activate an image slider. Here's the script :

```
    $(function(){var scroller=$("#scroller div.innerScrollArea");var scrollerContent=scroller.children("ul");scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);var curX=0;scrollerContent.children().each(function(){var $this=$(this);$this.css("left",curX);curX+=$this.width()});var fullW=curX/2;var viewportW=scroller.width();var controller={curSpeed:0,fullSpeed:2};var $controller=$(controller);var tweenToNewSpeed=function(newSpeed,duration){if(duration===undefined){duration=600}$controller.stop(true).animate({curSpeed:newSpeed},duration)};scroller.hover(function(){tweenToNewSpeed(0)},function(){tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed)});var doScroll=function(){var curX=scroller.scrollLeft();var newX=curX+controller.curSpeed;if(newX>fullW*2-viewportW){newX-=fullW}scroller.scrollLeft(newX)};setInterval(doScroll,20);tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed)});
```

I minified it manually. If I just upload this app to Heroku, it will give me a 500 internal server error. In the Heroku logs, I can see this :

```
    2013-01-02T04:50:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 640ms
    2013-01-02T04:50:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2013-01-02T04:50:59+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (slider.js isn't precompiled):
    2013-01-02T04:50:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <footer class="footer">
    2013-01-02T04:50:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <%= javascript_include_tag "slider" %> 
    2013-01-02T04:50:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: </footer>
```

So, I added the javascript to be pre-compiled by adding the following line to production.rb :

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w( slider.js )
```

With that, my app loaded but the javascript didn't work. When I check the source I see how Heroku have compiled my javascript :

```
$(function(){var a=$("#scroller div.innerScrollArea"),b=a.children("ul");b.children().clone().appendTo(b);var c=0;b.children().each(function(){var a=$(this);a.css("left",c),c+=a.width()});var d=c/2,e=a.width(),f={curSpeed:0,fullSpeed:2},g=$(f),h=function(a,b){b===undefined&&(b=600),g.stop(!0).animate({curSpeed:a},b)};a.hover(function(){h(0)},function(){h(f.fullSpeed)});var i=function(){var b=a.scrollLeft(),c=b+f.curSpeed;c>d*2-e&&(c-=d),a.scrollLeft(c)};setInterval(i,20),h(f.fullSpeed)});
```

Its a mess. My question is, how to fix this? I need heroku to compile my other scripts and css files. But to exclude only this file. How to do it?

Comment: Why does it matter if the local variables are renamed for compactness?

Comment: @muistooshort The script stops working after that. No idea how and why. But in my local system the script works but in Heroku it doesn't

Comment: have you actually precompiled the js? you should be able to find your code in your public/assets directory? If it's not there, you need to manually precompile your assets: rake assets:precompile

Comment: @DamonMannion Yes I have placed the assets in that directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than letting Heroku pre-compile the assets, many consider it better practice to pre-compile them yourself before pushing. This gives you a chance to check the compiled assets locally, and fix any errors that might occur, before pushing what you know works to Heroku.

You can do this in your repository with:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

And to clear out any existing precompiled assets (good practice to run this before precompile):

```
rake assets:clean
```

As for the "mess", what's actually happened is that the minifier has swapped out variable names for shorter ones. This has been normal behaviour for minifiers for years, and it's *unlikely* (but possible) that it's broken something. There's a reason to precompile assets locally and test to see whether that's the problem.

Comment: Then can you please tell me how to stop Heroku from precompiling? Because If I stop it by removing the line "config.assets.precompile += %w( slider.js )" it will give a 500 internal server error. When pre compiling locally, how to exclude that specific javascript?

Comment: If you add the `public/assets` directory to your version control (if git then `git add public/assets`), commit and push then Heroku will see that you already have an assets directory and won't precompile. It sounds like you need that slider.js file, so either keep that line in the config or add it to the application.js file (if using Rails 3 with asset pipeline).

Comment: But how to stop rails from precompiling that file and adding it with the original state? While precompiling other assets?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the compression that's causing it to fail? Try adding `config.assets.compress = false` to the configuration so that the assets don't get minified, but still include slider.js. If there's still an error you know it's not the compression's fault.

Comment: Ok i din't add compress = false... I just removed "config.assets.precompile += %w( slider.js )" and it didn't precompile the slider.js. After pushing to Heroku, I get the 500 internal server error! In the logs I see this : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 130ms
<footer class="footer">
<%= javascript_include_tag "slider" %> ...............
app/views/layouts/_footer.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_layouts__footer_html_erb___3244462626116790033_25246540'
ActionView::Template::Error (slider.js isn't precompiled):

Comment: Ok... but that's not what I suggested! This comment thread is getting too long - I'd recommend you reading up on [the asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: Ok I just removed the compression and it sops compressing all the files. Now, in Firefox the slider works. But in Chrome it won't. But in the local machine, the app works in both browsers!